# Flex mx.controls.DataGrid with conditionally editable cells

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, datagrid

I have a `mx.controls.DataGrid` datagrid on a page, and the requirement I have is that some *cells* on that datagrid be editable dependent upon some condition in the state of the system.

So far as I can tell I can set the entire datagrid to be editable via the `editable` property, or all values in a column via the `DataGridColumn`'s `editable` property, but I don't see a way to set this on the level of an individual cell within the datagrid.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good example you can find [here (Preventing a cell from being edited)](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf651fa-7ff1.html). It solves your problem completely. Just change the condition in the example to your own.

Comment: @Grabar, does he want to prevent it to be edited or the opposite?

Comment: @helloflash, What's the difference? With preventing to be edited he can do everything that he want.

Comment: @Grabar, this code `prohibits` editing of the Album `column`, nothing else... Adam says that he already knows how to do it.

Comment: Look at example better. This example show how to prevent editing of individual cell upon some dynamic conditions. With this code you can control "edit possibility" for each cell depending on some condition. P.S. My nickname is Crabar, not Grabar.

Comment: could you tell me how to answer to Adam question with your exemple?

Comment: Simple =). "and the requirement I have is that some cells on that datagrid be editable dependent upon some condition". Adam know how to set editable all DataGrid or some column, but he want to control editable "of an individual cell within the datagrid". So, with Adobe example, he can prevent editing for the cells that should be non-editable with any conditions that he want.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58481/discussion-between-helloflash-and-crabar).

Comment: @Adam Parkin, is that possible for you to tell me how you have transformed the code mentioned, to make editable one cell. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This works great:

```
// cell at the intersection of row 1 and column 2

dg.addEventListener(ListEvent.ITEM_CLICK, cellEditable);

function cellEditable(e:ListEvent):void {
   e.target.editable = (e.rowIndex == 1 && e.columnIndex === 2) ? true : false;
}
```

Comment: In the end, I went with the other method (tying an event handler to the itemEditBeginning event of the datagrid), but this is an equivalent way to achieve the same result.

Comment: @AdamParkin - Is that possible for you to show me the code you produced with the other method? Thanks.